# Not Able to Send Post Request

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am sending post request, below is my code :

```
  @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;


    public void postToAPI(MyRequest request){

       EventResponse Response = restTemplate.postForObject(PUSH_URL, request,EventResponse.class);
        
    }
```

Getting the below error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for MyRequest class
```

Added The following code but still same issue :

```
   List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
            messageConverters.add(converter);
            restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to print key values on console....
generally I construct post rest call this way

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("name", "xyz");
    map.put("designation", "Company");
    map.put("email", "abc@test.com");
    ResponseEntity<Void> voidResponseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8020/employee", map, void.class);
    System.out.println(voidResponseEntity);
```